# Get All Directories

Tags: .net, vb.net, vb.net-2010

I followed this [tutorial](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ms171645%28v=vs.100%29.aspx%20tutorial) to make a file explorer in Visual Basic 2010.

This line of code  `Dim info As New DirectoryInfo("../..")` gets the directory where ever the program was started.

I was wondering how I could force the program to list the directories on the C drive just by changing the previous line of code.

This is my code I have:

```
Private Sub PopulateTreeView()
    Dim rootNode As TreeNode

    Dim info As New DirectoryInfo("../..")
    If info.Exists Then
        rootNode = New TreeNode(info.Name)
        rootNode.Tag = info
        GetDirectories(info.GetDirectories(), rootNode)
        TreeView1.Nodes.Add(rootNode)
    End If

End Sub

Private Sub GetDirectories(ByVal subDirs() As DirectoryInfo, _
    ByVal nodeToAddTo As TreeNode)

    Dim aNode As TreeNode
    Dim subSubDirs() As DirectoryInfo
    Dim subDir As DirectoryInfo
    For Each subDir In subDirs
        aNode = New TreeNode(subDir.Name, 0, 0)
        aNode.Tag = subDir
        aNode.ImageKey = "folder"
        subSubDirs = subDir.GetDirectories()
        If subSubDirs.Length <> 0 Then
            GetDirectories(subSubDirs, aNode)
        End If
        nodeToAddTo.Nodes.Add(aNode)
    Next subDir

End Sub
Public Sub New()
    InitializeComponent()
    PopulateTreeView()

End Sub 'New
Private Sub treeView1_NodeMouseClick(ByVal sender As Object, _
ByVal e As TreeNodeMouseClickEventArgs) _
    Handles TreeView1.NodeMouseClick

    Dim newSelected As TreeNode = e.Node
    listView1.Items.Clear()
    Dim nodeDirInfo As DirectoryInfo = _
    CType(newSelected.Tag, DirectoryInfo)
    Dim subItems() As ListViewItem.ListViewSubItem
    Dim item As ListViewItem = Nothing

    Dim dir As DirectoryInfo
    For Each dir In nodeDirInfo.GetDirectories()
        item = New ListViewItem(dir.Name, 0)
        subItems = New ListViewItem.ListViewSubItem() _
            {New ListViewItem.ListViewSubItem(item, "Directory"), _
            New ListViewItem.ListViewSubItem(item, _
            dir.LastAccessTime.ToShortDateString())}

        item.SubItems.AddRange(subItems)
        listView1.Items.Add(item)
    Next dir
    Dim file As FileInfo
    For Each file In nodeDirInfo.GetFiles()
        item = New ListViewItem(file.Name, 1)
        subItems = New ListViewItem.ListViewSubItem() _
            {New ListViewItem.ListViewSubItem(item, "File"), _
            New ListViewItem.ListViewSubItem(item, _
            file.LastAccessTime.ToShortDateString())}

        item.SubItems.AddRange(subItems)
        listView1.Items.Add(item)
    Next file

    listView1.AutoResizeColumns(ColumnHeaderAutoResizeStyle.HeaderSize)

End Sub
```

Comment: You really didn't put much thought into this, did you?  Open Windows Explorer, select your C drive and then look at the path in the address bar.  That's the path you use.  Come back again when you've got an actual programming question to ask.

Comment: I tried that and I keep getting errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a try catch for that beaus there will be files you have no right to access.
So to let the code jump over it you use a Catch.

Otherwise you would get errors like you cant access the recycle files and so on.

So when you start your for each put a try there."like the code below"

change Dim info As New DirectoryInfo("../..") to Dim info As New DirectoryInfo("C:\")

```
Private Sub GetDirectories(ByVal subDirs() As DirectoryInfo, _
ByVal nodeToAddTo As TreeNode)

    Dim aNode As TreeNode
    Dim subSubDirs() As DirectoryInfo
    Dim subDir As DirectoryInfo


    For Each subDir In subDirs

        Try

            aNode = New TreeNode(subDir.Name, 0, 0)
            aNode.Tag = subDir
            aNode.ImageKey = "folder"
            subSubDirs = subDir.GetDirectories()
            If subSubDirs.Length <> 0 Then
                GetDirectories(subSubDirs, aNode)
            End If
            nodeToAddTo.Nodes.Add(aNode)
        Catch ex As Exception

        End Try

    Next subDir

End Sub
```

Comment: I got it working by using the code and running the program as admin. It took about 15 seconds to launch. Is there something I could do to make it load faster? I know this has nothing to do with the original question, but I am using a tree view and and a list view and I was wondering how I could make the tree view expand on form load. How could I also open a file in the list view by double clicking? Thanks!

Comment: @Jared_S beter ask a new question if you want to know different things.dificult to anwser in coments.and if I would add code to my anwser it will mybe confuse future readers.

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out. I needed to change the manifest file and run the program as administrator. Thank You for all the help.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that the current code only works if you have full access to all subdirectories of the path you choose to enumerate.

As a minimum you need some `Try ... Catch ... End Try` clauses to report and process permission denied errors.